# how to replace spaces inside doublequotes

Tags: replace, spaces, busybox

I need to replace every spaces inside doublequotes in a variable:

```
VAR='"this is my problem" but not yours'
```

Now i have to replace the spaces (may be more than one in a row) in "this is my problem" with '[[:space]]+'. My shell is busybox. What is the simplest way?

Thank you.

Comment: look up the `sed` command.

Comment: i have tryed several things with sed without success.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: things like `echo $var | sed 's|\s|[[:space:]]+|g'`

Comment: And what did you get back? Please edit your question to include all this info. From the initial look of things, that sed command should work.

Comment: this command returns
`"this[[:space:]]+is[[:space:]]+my[[:space:]]+problem"[[:space:]]+but[[:space:]]+not[[:space:]]+yours`
but i need
`"this[[:space:]]+is[[:space:]]+my[[:space:]]+problem" but not yours`
as result - like in the question above.

Comment: OOhhhh, I see. I missed the double quotes part. Give me a minute on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `echo $var | sed -re 's|.*("[^"]*").*|\1|g' | sed -re 's|\s|[[:space:]]+|g'`. First sed is to extra the double quotes part, the second sed is to  turn the spaces inside the double quotes into [[:space:]]+.

PS. You could have saved two hours if you put all the stuff in the comments into your original question from the start :)

Comment: thx. but it doesn't work:
`[machine] /var # echo $var | sed 's|.*("[^"]").*|\1|g' | sed 's|\s|[[:space:]]+|g'


"this[[:space:]]+is[[:space:]]+my[[:space:]]+problem"[[:space:]]+but[[:space:]]+not[[:space:]]+yours
`

Comment: Forgot to put a * after the [^"]. Fixed now.